# Add Property to StatelessComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

How does one add properties to stateless components?

For example, PrivateRoute is a stateless component used to prohibit navigation to certain routes when the users are not authenticated.
The route is accessed via a Router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
...
            <Router basename={baseUrl} >
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to='/public'>Public</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/protected'>Protected</Link></li>
                </ul>

                <PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} auth={true}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
```

My aim is to pass auth={true} (this will eventually become a flag updated based on a login page), however, I am receiving the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2339  (TS) Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

PrivateRoute is defined as follows:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Redirect, Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom"

type RouteComponent = React.StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<{}>> | React.ComponentClass<any>
const AUTHENTICATED = true;
export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<RouteProps> = ({ component,  ...rest }: any) => {
    const renderFn = (Component?: RouteComponent) => (props: RouteProps) => {
        if (!Component) { return null }
        console.log(props)
        if (AUTHENTICATED) { return <Component {...props} /> }

        const redirectProps = {
            to: {
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: props.location },
            },
        }

        return <Redirect {...redirectProps} />
    }

    return <Route {...rest} render={renderFn(component)} />
}
```

I have tried:

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<RouteProps> = ({ component, auth,  ...rest }: any) => {
    const renderFn = (Component?: RouteComponent) => (props: RouteProps) => {
```

as well as

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<RouteProps> = ({ component,  ...rest }: any, auth: boolean) => {
    const renderFn = (Component?: RouteComponent) => (props: RouteProps) => {
```

and

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<RouteProps> = ({ component,  ...rest }: any) => {
    const renderFn = (Component?: RouteComponent, auth: boolean) => (props: RouteProps) => {
```

Lastly, I've tried sending in the value via a variable:

```
let authenticated = false
<PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} {...authenticated}/>
```

When doing so I am unable to find this in either props, rest, or Component.

Comment: I think that you could probably use a Higher Order Component (HOC) here. Wrap your Protected component in a HOC that will take in the value of auth and pass that into the props of Protected. https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a Typescript error, not a react one. Assuming that `auth` is a custom property of yours, you'll need to do the following to get it to work:

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  auth?: boolean;
}
export const PrivateRoute: React.StatelessComponent<PrivateRouteProps> = ({component, auth, ...rest})
```

Doing `SFC<RouteProps & { auth?: boolean }>` should also work as well. The point is that you can't add on props in React TSX without either declaring `props` to be `any` or declaring the type of additional props. I don't believe there is a way to make `tsconfig.json` skip over this check entirly, but there might be a way.

Comment: When doing this, how do I then pass the variable to the component?
When trying this:
<PrivateRoute exact path='/upload' component={Upload} auth={false}/>
OR
<PrivateRoute exact path='/upload' component={Upload} auth=false/>

I'm getting an error: TS2339 (TS) Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.